# why dose the SelectionChanged event be triggered automatically when binding the ItemSoure of listbox to View property of CellectionViewSource?

Tags: windows-phone-7

does anyone know  why dose  the SelectionChanged  event be triggered automatically when  binding the ItemSoure of listbox to View property of CellectionViewSource?how can i stop this?thanks.the code as below:

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListboxDataTemplate}"  x:Name="AllListBox"  SelectedItem="      Binding Master.SelectedTask,Mode=TwoWay}"   ItemsSource="{Binding Master.ViewSource.View}" />

//Code-behind
CollectionViewSource   ViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
            ViewSource.Source = Tasks;
            ViewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Model.t_state", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            ViewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Model.t_createtime", ListSortDirection.Descending));
            ViewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Model.t_importance", ListSortDirection.Descending));
            ViewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Model.t_nam", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the SelectedItem or SelectedIndex at any point of time in your code behind?

Comment: yep, both the two properties are initialized, when the page is beging navigated to,in the OnNavigatedTo method.      this.AllListBox.SelectedIndex= -1;SelectedTask=null.if i do not sort the thse items for this listbox by using CollectionViewSource,it won't be triggered once the page is loaded

Comment: when ever you change these values, the selection changed event is triggered. You may verify this by using break points. I would recommend not to initialize them in OnNavigatedTo method.